# Кастомное меню для программы на WPF

Tags: wpf, menu

[image: Меню]

Требуется сделать такое меню, но идей по реализации не очень много - использовать ListBox или, может, будет достаточно Grid. (мало опыта работы с WPF)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать наиболее верно? (hover-эффект и смена цвета элемента по нажатию должны присутствовать)

Comment: `ListBox` с кастомным шаблоном элемента подойдет

Comment: Взять `WPF Metro` и не изобретать велосипед :)